# How to install a new language for Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016

I have Czech localization and so I'd like to install English language to my Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 (just to be able to easily post screenshots etc. here when I post questions).

First I tried to download [Language Accessory Pack](https://support.microsoft.com/cs-cz/office/sada-language-accessory-pack-pro-office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fOffice-Language-Interface-Pack-LIP-downloads-D63007C2-E8AE-41FD-8BFB-FCE2857010E1&ui=cs-CZ&rs=cs-CZ&ad=CZ#ID0EAACAAA=Newer_versions) for my version of Office (this is Czech version of the page, but if you go there from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026353/office-install-the-language-accessory-packs-for-office-2016), you will probably get the English one). the problem was that when I ran it, I got this error message, which I don't quite understand:

[image]

Maybe it is suggesting to go through the installer somehow? So I went to "Add or remove programs" / Office / Modify, but it looks like it cannot be done this way - or can be? : [image]

How to proceed?

**EDIT:**

*Q: Have you tried the option to download from File->Options->Language, then clicking on "Install additional displayed languages from Office.com?*

Response: Seems that I don't have that link there. It should probably be like it is [here](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/12/01/how-to-change-the-language-of-microsoft-office/). But there is just a title which reads "Display installed languages" and when clicking on it it just opens a table which shows that I have only Czech language installed:

[image]

Comment: Try this 64bit- https://c2rsetup.officeapps.live.com/c2r/download.aspx?ProductreleaseID=languagepack&language=cs-cz&platform=x64&source=O16LAP&version=O16GA && 32-bit https://c2rsetup.officeapps.live.com/c2r/download.aspx?ProductreleaseID=languagepack&language=cs-cz&platform=x86&source=O16LAP&version=O16GA && follow these instructions after installation (select office 16 section) - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/language-accessory-pack-for-office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#BKMK_language&ID0EAACAAA=Office_2016

Comment: @Madhubala interesting. The first link (64 bit) says that I don't have a compatible version of MS Office - error code 30053-1011 (0). I just checked and I do have 64 bit Windows 10 and MS Excel 2016...

Comment: Try second link : 32-bit

Comment: @Madhubala why 32 bit, when I have 64 bit Windows and Office?

Comment: **You can't use Click to Run since you installed Office 2016 with an MSI.**  Where does the link in the error dialog take you exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound, [this is the link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-installed-with-click-to-run-and-windows-installer-on-same-computer-isn-t-supported-30775ef4-fa77-4f47-98fb-c5826a6926cd?ns=ocsac2rclicktorun&version=16&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=ccl160&helpid=%2212-bootstrapper_prereq-sxs_c2r_over_msi%22&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us). I don't understand the whole thing about the `click-to-run` and MSI... I just don't want to re-install anything, don't wanna mess up my current installation. Is there a solution that would work with my current installation?

Comment: Have you tried the option to download from File->Options->Language, then clicking on "Install additional displayed languages from Office.com?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio please see my response with screenshot at the end of my post.

Comment: @Tomas - It’s not difficult to understand.  Your downloading the language packs for the Click To Run version of Office.  You have the MSI installation which is incompatible with what your downloading.  You should be using the Office configuration tool to install the language packs in question.

Comment: @Ramhound  *"You should be using the Office configuration tool to install the language packs in question"* - where? How? Cannot google it. Perhaps it's named slightly differently? I hope you don't mean the thing which I show in the second screenshot - I wasn't successful there...

Comment: @Tomas - [Its linked on the page you provided](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployOffice/use-the-office-deployment-tool-to-install-volume-licensed-editions-of-visio-2016?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252f82691bd7-a3d5-47ca-8d8a-0ee43ec2c01f)

Comment: @Tomas - The link from your comment.    I went ahead and linked to the Office configuration tool

Comment: @Ramhound ok, thanks. So out of these, do I use the *deployment* tool or *customization* tool?

Comment: @Ramhound ... hmm... Ran the setup.exe and nothing... seems like I need to edit an XML file... to add product id... , Omg why is this *so complicated*? Such thing which should be super easy...

Comment: @Tomas - The deployment tool is the tool you use to customize your Office installation.  As to the reason, it's complicate (but it really isn't to those with experience), you are the one with the VLK Office installation, are you sure you have the permissions to change your office installation?  [This](https://config.office.com/deploymentsettings) will let you generate the correct XML to download the languages you want.  This isn't for the unexperienced, if you are not the administrator, it might be easier to just ask them to do it.

Comment: @Tomas - I'm sorry to haunt a 2 year old question, but did you manage to solve this? I have the same problem but for Dutch localization.

Answer (score 0):

For volume licensed versions of Office 2016 which use MSI technology, such as Office Professional Plus 2016, Office Standard 2016, to get the language package or installation file, it needs to login into [VLSC](https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/servicecenter/) (Volume Licensing Service Center).

More detailed information, please refer to "[Download language packs, language interface packs, and proofing tools for volume license versions of Office](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/office2016/customize-language-setup-and-settings-for-office-2016#download-language-packs-language-interface-packs-and-proofing-tools-for-volume-license-versions-of-office)"

The language package from "Language Accessory Pack" are for Office which use C2R technology, such as Office Home & Student 2016, Office Home & Business 2016 and ect.